# What is Federal and industry regulations PCI, SOX, GLBA, ISO 17799, HIPAA, CA1386?

Tags: encryption, authentication, web-application, network, privacy

Often i see in job post they mention like "Federal and industry regulations understanding (e.g., PCI, SOX, GLBA, ISO 17799, HIPAA, CA1386)"

But what are those exactly, are those kind of rocket science like protocols or algorithm or standard instructions to do organised way of management work?

Has anyone some knowledge about that please?

Answer (score 2):

These are all requirements and standards for security controls related to data security/privacy of sensitive information (personal, financial, health, etc). As the description says, they are mostly US federal (SOX, GLBA, HIPPA) or industry (PCI, ISO 17799) standards, although CA 1386 is a US state law.

Since the job posting mentions quite a few standards, my guess is they're looking for experience working in an industry with a regulated information security space. That would imply you have experience navigating a formal security program that tracks risks, controls, requirements, and exceptions/issues.

You can read about each if you're interested:

- [PCI](http://pcisecuritystandards.org)
- [SOX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarbanes%E2%80%93Oxley_Act)
- [GLBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramm%E2%80%93Leach%E2%80%93Bliley_Act)
- [ISO 17799](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=39612)
- [HIPPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act)
- [CA 1386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_S.B._1386)